# dashed border UIImageView swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to add a dashed border using `CALayer` on a `UIImageView`. I've found a method, but is that working in swift and how can i convert it to swift? o have another imageView which has a border so would be the best solution to use `CALayer`, so they look similar? How can i obtain this

obj-c code to swift?

```
- (CAShapeLayer *) addDashedBorderWithColor: (CGColorRef) color {
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    CGSize frameSize = self.size;

    CGRect shapeRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
    [shapeLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
    [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake( frameSize.width/2,frameSize.height/2)];

    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:color];
    [shapeLayer setLineWidth:5.0f];
    [shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
    [shapeLayer setLineDashPattern:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
  nil]];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:shapeRect cornerRadius:15.0];
    [shapeLayer setPath:path.CGPath];

    return shapeLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I would do simply like this in the custom view class:

Updated for **Swift 4**

```
class DashedBorderView: UIView {

    let _border = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        _border.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        _border.fillColor = nil
        _border.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
        self.layer.addSublayer(_border)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        _border.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius:10).cgPath
        _border.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully, I edited it a bit to make it more general. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make an attempt to convert the code to Swift first. If you have problems, post the problem you are having.

I'll get you started:

```
func addDashedBorderWithColor(color: UIColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let frameSize = self.bounds.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Updated for Swift 3:

if you want to make your ImageView/ UIView/ UILabel / UITextField as dashed border then used below simple lines of code;

```
func makeDashedBorder()  {

    let mViewBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    mViewBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.magenta.cgColor
    mViewBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
    mViewBorder.frame = mYourAnyTypeOfView.bounds
    mViewBorder.fillColor = nil
    mViewBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: mYourAnyTypeOfView.bounds).cgPath
    mYourAnyTypeOfView.layer.addSublayer(mViewBorder)
}
```

**// Note : where,  mYourAnyTypeOfView  = UIView/ UIImageView/ UILabel/ UITextField and etc.**

// Enjoy coding..!